# ctest and MPI parallel tests

Tags: cmake, mpi, googletest, ctest

I'm trying to build some tests with [googleTest](https://github.com/google/googletest/) which should test some MPI parallel code. Ideally I want our CI server to execute them through `ctest`.

My naive approach was to simply call ctest with `MPI`:

```sh
mpirun -n 3 ctest
```

However, this results in even trivial tests failing as long as at least two are executed.

Example of a trivial tests:

```cpp
TEST(TestSuite, DummyTest1) {
  EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}
TEST(TestSuite, DummyTest2) {
  EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}
```

Am I supposed to launch `ctest` in some other way? Or do I have to approach this completely differently?

Additional info:

- The tests are added via `gtest_discover_tests()`.
- Launching the test executable directly with MPI (`mpirun -n 3 testExe`) yields successful tests but I would prefer using `ctest`.
- Version info:

  - googletest: 1.11.0
  - MPI: OpenMPI 4.0.3 AND MPICH 3.3.2

Comment: `mpirun ctest` will spawn three identical instances of `ctest` that will in turn spawn MPI singletons (e.g. MPI job with only one task) so this is unlikely the right approach. Have a look at https://github.com/LLNL/gtest-mpi-listener instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/ctest-and-mpi-parallel-googletests/5557) CMake Forum post, which links to a Merge Requests and an issue in the CMake GitLab repository, `gtest_discover_tests()` currently simply doesn't support MPI.

A possible workaround is to abuse the `CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR` property to inject the wrapper into the test command. However, this changes the whole target and not only the tests so your mileage may vary.

```
set_property(TARGET TheExe PROPERTY CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR '${MPIEXEC_EXECUTABLE} ${MPIEXEC_NUMPROC_FLAG} 3')
gtest_discover_tests(TheExe)
```

See the forum post for a full minimal example.